# zero inflated poisson model, how to choose "inflate" variables

Tags: poisson-regression, zero-inflation, poisson-process

I am trying to run a zero-inflated Poisson regression. The data I have are number of West Nile Virus cases *NoCases* (dependent var), and my independent variables are AvgTemp, AvgPrecipitaion, Region (*Numbered 1-4). Over 60% of my dependent variable data are Zeros.

What I need to know, is when setting up this regression in Stata, how do I determine which variables to list in the "inflate" (aka certain zero) section? I don't understand what they are asking for.

Comment: Please check this:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.4268
New variable selection methods for zero‐inflated count data with applications to the substance abuse field

Comment: please check this from statlist.org:
https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1370410-how-to-use-and-interpret-zero-inflated-poisson